# How can I automate creating an expandable table in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this light-weight JQuery plug-in titled Expand to create an expandable table: 
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/expand-table-rows-with-jquery-jexpand-plugin/

However, the information I would like to have on this table is very large. I would like to automate inserting images from an image directory into each expandable row. How would this be possible on JQuery? I can do it manually with the `<img src>` tag but I have close to 4000 rows in this table.

Many Thanks! Happy to post more information

Comment: How is the information currently being stored/where is it coming from? Unless everything follows some sort of pattern you can't really "generate" information. You could theoretically look through the file system using server-sided code, but this cannot be done using Browser-based JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: I have a folder with all the images I'd like to insert in each expandable row. The code for table is HTML/CSS. Do you have any ideas as to what would be a good way to automate the creation of a large expandable table? Many thanks -

Comment: JavaScript (outside of node.js) is a client-side language, meaning it does have direct access to the server nor its file system. If you haven't already, I suggest you look into setting up a server. Popular server languages/frameworks include php, Node.js, and ASP.NET (C#).